# Calculate the running time of merge sort

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

when you want to calculate the running time for merge sort, which is correct put the startTime before call the function of mergeSort or after call:

```
    startTime=System.nanoTime();
    mergeSort(temp,0,temp.length - 1);
    endTime=System.nanoTime();
    running-time=(endTime-startTime);
```

or

```
    mergeSort(temp,0,temp.length - 1);
    startTime=System.nanoTime();
    endTime=System.nanoTime();
    duration=(endTime-startTime);
```

Which is correct because the result is different?

Comment: First one is correct, the second one achieves nothing related to the timing of mergeSort

Comment: The difference between the start time and the end time accounts only for those program actions that occur between the two calls to `nanoTime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct as it gets the time before the operation (the merge sort), performs the operation and then gets the time after it, using both of these times to calculate the time taken.

The second one is incorrect as it performs the operation and then does calculations with the times, and the time it calculates is nothing to do with the time it took to run the merge sort algorithm.

Note: The variable `running-time` is invalid. Consider changing it to `runningTime`, or at worst `running_time`.

Comment: *"it is just calculating the time it takes to call `System.nanoTime();` twice and assign it to two variables."*: this is not quite accurate.

Comment: @trincot true, actually. I will edit that accordingly.

Comment: OK, you removed any claim of what the second code *does* measure. Do you know what it measures?

Comment: @tincot I can't pretend to be a JVM expert, but it is likely just the time between the two calls (as the CPU will likely switch away from the Java process to do other stuff during this time)